# Advice for Adobe CC shared storage solutions

Tags: premiere, software-recommendation, storage

We're considering building an Adobe video production environment and we need a shared storage solution. We have had impressive presentations from **EditShare** and **OpenDrives/CatDV**.  Our production environment includes 4 video edit suites and 3 motion graphics workstations in a mixed PC/Mac environment. I'd be interested in hearing any first hand experience with latency/speed, and ease of user interface.